# Output from mySql a two dimensional Json but with duplicates

Tags: php, mysql, json, multidimensional-array, duplicates

mySql outputs this:
[image]

As you can see row 3 and 4 has duplicates so I want to merge these duplicates when I output my Json. To be exact I want my json to be like this:

```
[
    {
        "name": "The Crane Bar",
        "lat": "53.2692",
        "lng": "-9.06151",
        "events": [
            {
                "name": "Traditional music session",
                "info": null
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Taaffes Bar",
        "lat": "53.2725",
        "lng": "-9.05321",
        "events": [
            {
                "name": "6 Nations, Italy VS Ireland",
                "info": null
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "a house",
        "lat": "37.4401",
        "lng": "-122.143",
        "events": [
            {
                "name": "Party at Palo Alto",
                "info": "Some info about the party"
            },
            {
                "name": "2gdfgdf",
                "info": "2gdfgdfgdf"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

You know use one one location_name, lat and lng and have nested the event_name and post_content (as info here).

Thanks!

Comment: Is this your actual table structure or have jou performed a `JOIN`?

Comment: @Lorenz your guess is correct, it is a (simplified for here) product of a `JOIN` of two tables with also a couple of `WHERE`. `location_id` is the one that I use for the `JOIN`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment, you want the results to be nested, so when you generate the JSON, iterate over the rows and build a nested result list in PHP:

```
$result = array();
$item = null;

for ($i = 0; $i < count($rows); ++$i) {
  $row = $rows[$i];

  if ($item === null) {
    $item = array('location' => $row['location'], 'events' => array());
  }

  $item['events'][] = array('name' => $row['event_name']);

  if ($i == count($rows) - 1 || $row['location'] != $rows[$i + 1]['location']) {
    $result[] = $item;
    $item = null;
  }
}

echo json_encode($result);  // JSON-encoded data
```

Now each location will have an `events` list with one or more entries.

Comment: unfortunately that doesn't help in my script because I want the duplicate locations having inside them the as many as the events might be.

Comment: Thanks a lot this seem to work but one more question: is the `$rows`  the following `$query = mysql_query('SELECT...'); $rows = mysql_fetch_array($query);` ? Because I'm having some odd results. (I have the correct names under `$row['name']` based on my db)